# Checkbox disable when amount in textbox exceed

Tags: jquery

I have this code and working properly however when i clear the text field the checkbox remain checked what should i do ?

```
   <form name="form1">
    <div class="controlset-pad">
        <input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" class="medium" disabled='disabled'/>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" class="medium" disabled='disabled'/>
    </div>


        $('input[name=other_name]').keyup(function(){
            if (this.value.length > 0) {
               $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', false)
            } else {
               $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', true)      
            }
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H8VPY/47/

Comment: suggest adding other events along with keyup for accounting for mouse events etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script as follows. It simply unchecks before disabling the control.

```
$('input[name=other_name]').keyup(function(){
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
       $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
       $('input[name="others"]').attr('checked', false);
       $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', true)      
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the change event as well for mouse base edits such as right-click>cut etc.

Note:  Uncheck before disabling checkboxes.

```js
$('input[name=other_name]').bind('keyup change', function() {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $('input[name="others"]').attr('checked', false);
    $('input[name="others"]').prop('disabled', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1">
  <div class="controlset-pad">
    <input type="checkbox" name="others" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" class="medium" disabled='disabled' />
  </div>

  <div class="field4">
    <label>Name on credit card if different from above</label>
    <input type="text" name="other_name" class="medium" />
  </div>
</form>
```